# Django admin userlinks is not showing up

Tags: django, django-forms

I extended base_site.html template and it's working correctly.

```
{% extends "admin/base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}

{% block title %}
    {% trans 'Test Admin' %}
{% endblock %}

{% block userlinks %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
```

And now I've created a template for my submit form which looks like this.

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}
{% load i18n static %}

{% block userlinks %}
    {{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}
```

But no userlinks is showing up.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a closer look at 'base.html', you will notice that user links are only displayed if has_permission is true.
For my case, I passed has_permission and the user object to my template, and the links appeared.

```
return render(request, 'account/activate/activate_department_reps.html',
                  {'department_reps': department_reps, 'has_permission': True, 'user': request.user})
```